# How to fetch all image URL when checkbox is clicked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scriptlet

I want to fetch only image urls from the concat values of price and pic url. But when i select checkbox with different images still it print first selected image url all the time.

when i try to print split value all price and image urls are displayed in an array in [price,imageurl]form i.e[5,imgurl,7,...] but when i try to print res[1] index wise only single image url comes all the time even if i select different pictures from checkbox

```
 <input name="product" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="product" value="<%=price+"&"+photo_url+"&"%>" onclick="totalIt()" />
```

```
function totalIt() {  
 var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  total=0;

 var count=0;
 for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
   if (input[i].checked) {
     total += parseInt(input[i].value);
     totalpicscost+=input[i].value;
     var f=totalvaluepics.toString();
     res = totalpicscost.split("&");
     count++;
   }

   //console.log("nearestvalue"+res[res.length-1]);
 }
 document.getElementById("pics").value = count;
 document.getElementById("total").value = "Rs " + total.toFixed(2);
 totalvaluepics= [totalpicscost];
  console(res[0]);
 }
```

I expect output to print all selected pictures url not same image url displaying all the time i select checkbox.

Comment: You do know that you can use any given `id` value only once per page? No more than one element can have the same `id` value, `id` **must be unique**.

Comment: I have given one id value but i have concatenated two values in input type

Answer (score 0):

It was quite not easy to understand your question, neither to read your code, please do not consider it to be offensive, but you need to work a bit more on JS styleguides and good practices to get rid of bad ones.

Regarding your question (as far as I understood it):

```
    function totalIt() {

      // Get all inputs
      const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[name="product"]');

      // Filter out inputs that are checked
      // and map them according to "splitValueIntoPriceAndUrl()" function declared below
      // so the data we need looks like 
      // [{price: 5, imageUrl:'imgurl'}, {price: 7, imageUrl:'imgurl2'}, ...]
      let checkedInputsValues = [ ...inputs ].filter(i => i.checked).map(splitValueIntoPriceAndUrl);

      // as far as I understood from given example,
      // you want to store the count of selected pics in #pics (and why is it an input??)
      document.querySelector('#pics').value = checkedInputsValues.length;

      // and also as far as I understood from given example,
      // you want to store total price into another input#total value,
      // so we reduce our checkedInputsWalues array in a way
      // to calculate all prices together
      const total = checkedInputsValues.reduce((totalPrice, { price }) => totalPrice += price, 0).toFixed(2)
      document.querySelector('#total').value = `Rs ${total}`;

      // and now we are collecting the image urls in res array.
      // now res[] values should be logged (at least).
      const res = checkedInputsValues.map(({ imageUrl }) => imageUrl);
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        console.log(res[i]);
      }

      // remapper helper
      function splitValueIntoPriceAndUrl(checkbox) {
        return {
          price: parseInt(checkbox.value.split('&')[0]),
          imageUrl: checkbox.value.split('&')[1]
        }
      }

      return res;
    }
```

Regarding your codestyle and practices:

1. You've declared some variables you had never use: `var inputVal = document.getElementById("second");`, `var f=totalvaluepics.toString();`. Don't do that.
2. Don't assign values to undeclared variables.
3. Switch to ES6 and functional methods of arrays/collections - it is helpful.

Comment: What is the value that you have passed in function because its showing value.split is not a function  in splitValueIntoPriceAndUrl(value);

Comment: @pratival My bad. I've passed the whole checkbox into this function instead of its value. Will correct my answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: But where did you define checkbox

Comment: @pratival it is defined "on the fly". Step by step from the declaration of `checkedInputsValues` variable: 1. `[...inputs]` - we are destructing the `HTMLCollection` of `<input name="product">` collected before, into the array (we turn HTMLCollection instance into Array instance, so we are can use `Array.prototype.*` methods). 2. `.filter(i => i.checked)` - here we are filtering out those checkboxes (in our array) which are not checked. So checkboxes left in this array after filtering, are actually defined for `splitValueIntoPriceAndUrl` callback, so we pass it in `.map()` as a reference.

Comment: @pratival I've tried to replicate your case in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98bkLe0s/), is that what you want?